# AspectJ Before and After pointcut not logging on entering/exiting method in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have been trying to have aspect to log as soon as we enter a method and exit a method the method signature with requestID etc but it doesn't work unfortunately. there is no error even while enabling debug log level. Any help will be very much appreciated.

**Package Structure:**

```
com.demo
    - config
       - LoggerAspect.java
    - controller
    - service
    - Application.java
```

**Configuration:**

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class LoggerAspect {
    private static final String TRACE_ID_LOG_VAR_NAME = "traceId";
    private org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Before("execution(* com.demo.*.*(..))")
    public void  before(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        logger.info("[" + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName() + "] [" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName()
                + "] [ " + MDC.get(TRACE_ID_LOG_VAR_NAME)
                + "] Entering ...");
    }

    @After("execution(* com.demo.*.*(..))")
    public void after(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        logger.info("[" + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName() + "] [" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName()
                + "] [ " + MDC.get(TRACE_ID_LOG_VAR_NAME)
                + "] Leaving ...");
    }

    @AfterThrowing("execution(* com.demo.*.*(..)))")
    public void AfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        logger.info("[" + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName() + "] [" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName()
                + "] [ " + MDC.get(TRACE_ID_LOG_VAR_NAME)
                + "] AfterThrowing ...");
    }

}
```

**Pom.xml :**

```
  +               <dependency>
+                       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
+                       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
+               </dependency>
+               <dependency>
+                       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
+                       <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
+               </dependency>
+               <dependency>
+                       <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
+                       <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
+                       <version>1.9.6</version>
+               </dependency>
+               <dependency>
+                       <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
+                       <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
+                       <version>1.9.6</version>
+                       <scope>runtime</scope>
+               </dependency>
```

App log:

```
    2021-12-06 14:44:35 ERROR [o.s.boot.SpringApplication] [] Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.demo.Application.main(Application.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:414)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[/demo] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:171)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:109)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Comment: modify the expression to `"execution(* com.demo..*.*(..))"` . After `demo` two `..` , which indicates any sub package under demo.

Comment: If I add that . then server doesn't start.. It throws illigalstateexception

Comment: Without seeing the code or log , not sure what is wrong . could you try "execution(* com.demo.controller.*.*(..))" and verify if the advise happens as expected ?

Comment: Thanks, execution(* com.demo.controller.*.*(..)) is working .. how to include for all sub packages under demo?

Comment: `com.demo..*.*` is the way to go for sub packages.  Could you share the log when this fails ? I also have couple of suggestions for your aspect code

Comment: Could you remove `@Configuration @EnableAspectJAutoProxy` from `LoggerAspect` and annotate `LoggerAspect` with `@Aspect @Component` ? After this confirm if the `IllegalStateException` gets thrown for `execution(* com.demo..*.*(..))`

Comment: It's still giving illigalstateexception..

Comment: Please update the error log to the question

Comment: Added log. Please check

Comment: Not sure what is wrong . could you try moving the class `Application` and package `config` a level up , i.e under `com` and retry. The idea is to isolate what is contributing to the error. If you still have error , please share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) .

Comment: An `@Aspect` is not a `@Configuration` but a `@Component`. Please create a separate `@Configuration` class. Config and aspect proxies are handled differently, do not mix them. If changing the pointcut to `execution(* com.demo..*.*(..))` leads to an exception, the pointcut is not the problem and the exception only a symptom of the real problem. Besides, you can shorten the suggested pointcut to `execution(* com.demo..*(..))`, there is no need to put an extra `*.` for the class name. R.G is right: Where is your MCVE? SO is not a discussion forum. Nobody likes to guess about incomplete code.